# WriteToText is only writing to temp files

Tags: python, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to Apache Beam, and attempting to write my first pipeline in Python to output data from a Google Pub/Sub subscription to flat files for later use; ideally I want to batch these up into a file for say every half an hour.  I have the following code as the final transform in my pipeline:-

```py
| 'write output' >> WriteToText('TestNewPipeline.txt')
```

However all the files that are created are in a directory prefixed "beam-temp-TestNewPipeline.txt-[somehash]" and batched into groups of 10, which is not what I was expecting.

I've tried playing with the window function, but it doesn't seem to have had much effect, so either I'm totally misunderstanding the concept or doing something completely wrong.

The code for the window is:-

```py
 | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(5))
```

I assumed this would result in the output to text file being written in a static five second window, bit this is not the case.

Full code below:-

```py
options = PipelineOptions()
options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming=True

def format_message(message, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):    
    formatted_message = {
        'data': message.data,
        'attributes': str(message.attributes),
        'timestamp': float(timestamp)
    }

    return formatted_message

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    (p
    | 'Read From Pub Sub' >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription='projects/[my proj]/subscriptions/[my subscription]',with_attributes=True)
    | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(5))
    | 'Map Message' >> beam.Map(format_message)
    | 'write output' >> WriteToText('TestNewPipeline.txt')
    )
result = p.run()
```

As expected, the process runs indefinitely and successfully reads messages from the subscription; however it only writes them to the beam-temp files.  Is anyone able to help point out where I'm going wrong?

Update:

Following comments from Jason, I've amended the pipeline a little more:-

```py
class AddKeyToDict(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        return [(element['rownumber'], element)]

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (p
        | 'Read From Pub Sub' >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_subscription)# can't make attributes work as yet! ,with_attributes=True) 
        # failed attempt 1| 'Map Message' >> beam.Map(format_message)
        # failed attempt 2| 'Parse JSON' >> beam.Map(format_message_element)
        | 'Parse to Json' >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
        | 'Add key' >> beam.ParDo(AddKeyToDict())
        | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(5), trigger=AfterProcessingTime(15), accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
        | 'Group' >> beam.GroupByKey()
        | 'write output' >> WriteToText(known_args.output_file)
        )
```

I've not been able to extract the message_id or published time from PubSub as yet, so I'm just using a rownumber generated in my message.  At this point, I'm still only getting the temporary files created, and nothing accumulated into a final file?  Starting to wonder if the Python implementation is still a bit lacking and I'm going to have to pick up Java....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From engaging with the Apache Beam Python guys, streaming writes to GCS (or local filesystem) is not yet supported in Python, hence why the streaming write does not occur; only unbounded targets are currently supported (e.g. Big Query tables).

Apparently this will be supported in the upcoming release of Beam for Python v2.14.0.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apache Beam's documentation on Windowing Constraints](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing-constraints):

> If you set a windowing function using the `Window` transform, each element is assigned to a window, but the windows are not considered until `GroupByKey` or `Combine` aggregates across a window and key.

Since there doesn't seem to be a notion of keys in this example, can you try using `Combine`?

Comment: I wondered if it might be something to do with that.  Ideally, I would want to use the message id from PubSub as the key in this case.  I've amended the Read From Pub Sub transformation to include the id_label argument, but I'm not sure then how I would be able to process this as a key in order to do the GroupByKey?
```| 'Read From Pub Sub' >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_subscription,id_label='MESSAGE_ID',with_attributes=True)```

Comment: You need to use beam.Map to turn the message into a KV with the message id as the key. Because GroupByKey operates on KVs. I am not sure how to do this in Python, but there is ample documentation for doing it in Java.

Comment: OK thank you, I'll try and work through that.  Unfortunately I'm not proficient in Python, but even less proficient in Java hence selecting the former to learn this!  To clarify, in the KV the message_id would be the key and the entire message content the value?

Comment: I've managed to add the KV pair in, not from the message_id as I simply can't work out how to extract that from anywhere.  Updated the main body with the changes; still doesn't seem to be working properly.

Comment: You can use the [id_label argument to ReadFromPubSub](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.13.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub) to get the message id populated into the attributes map, which you can then read in your format_message function.

Comment: Unfortunately, id_label is not support for the direct runner, returning the following error ```NotImplementedError: DirectRunner: id_label is not supported for PubSub reads``` which is a bit irritating for testing.

I've amended my pipeline to write to BigQuery, which is working (think due to being an unbounded target) but still can't get at the message id even when using id_label.  I was expecting it to be in the attributes property, but when parsing the list of dictionary keys returned, the message id and publish time are not exposed:-
```attributesstring = str(list(attributesdict))```

Comment: This is a known issue. A [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3489) has been filed in JIRA for exposing message_id in PubsubMessage. Please vote up this bug report.